# How to show the same domain name in every page? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

im a new programmer, and I want to know how can I show the same domain name in every page on my website?
For example: the domain name is www.domain.com and I have a page called Contact.aspx ,So I want to see the domain name only (www.domain.com) in the address bar when I click on "contact" instead of www.domain.com/Contact.aspx
I know that people cant bookmark my site if I do it and I still want to do it.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: By any chance are you looking for single page applications?
take a look at this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx

Comment: no, its not what im looking for..
Im looking for an example..

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`

Using that in every case you will see always the first address that the user have used